# Surefire way of determining the codec of a media file

Tags: wrapper, codec

I'm looking for a surefire way of determining the codec used in an audio or video file.  The two things I am currently using are the file extension (obvious), and the mime type as determined by running `file -ib' on the file.

This doesn't seem to get me all the way there: loads of formats are `wrapper' formats that hide the exact codec used within -- for example, '.ogg' files can internally use the Vorbis, Speex, or FLAC codecs.  Their MIME type is also usually hidden under 'application/ogg' or similar.

The `file' program is apparently able to tell me which codec is used, but it returns this as human-readable prose:

```
kb.ogg: Ogg data, Vorbis audio, stereo, 44100 Hz, ~0 bps
```

and as such it is dodgy to use programmatically.

What I'm essentially asking is: **is there a script out there (any language) that can wade through these wrapper formats and tell me what the meat of the file is made of?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) includes a library called libavformat that can open and demux pretty much any media format. Obviously that's more than you actually need, but I don't think you can find anything else that's quite as complete. I've used it myself with great success. Take a look at [this article](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html) for an introduction. There's also bindings for these libraries for some common scripting languages, such as [python](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/).

(If you don't want to build something using the library, you can probably use the regular ffmpeg binary.)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use your own `magic` file, copied and modified from the pre-installed `magic` file, and change the return string so that it can be easily parsed by your program.

See:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/file
- http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic